# How to access the team build completed event in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, plugins, tfs, tfsbuild

I would like to make a VS2010 plugin, which notifies me when a team build completed/failed. So far so good, but I have no idea how I can access these information programatically.

Thanks for help,

Eny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [TFS eventing system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507647.aspx). If you want to use WCF, see [this blog post](http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/08/02/How-to-use-WCF-to-subscribe-to-the-TFS-2010-Event-Service-rolling-up-hours.aspx) on how to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the source code of [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/BasicSCCProvider) Visual Studio sample plugin helps you to build your plugin and how communicate with the source control provider.

Hope helps!